# How to connect "Database" with Turbo C++?

Tags: ms-access, database-connection, turbo-c++

I want to connect "Microsoft Access" with "Turbo C++". How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using Turbo C++. There are many better free alternatives.

That said, you probably need to create an ODBC connection first and then use the DB classes to connect to that connection.

EDIT: I just remembered that Turbo C++ compiler was probably 16 bit. So, it won't be able to connect to a 32-bit ODBC Connection. Switch to a better C++ compiler ASAP if you want to do some real work.

Comment: Please give me the alternatives.

Comment: Looks like you are working on Windows. In that case, download Visual C++ 2008 Express edition.

Comment: Visual C++ 2008/2010? http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2008-Visual-CPP